# Не собирается проект VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

При сборке проекта ошибка:

> .vs\restore.dg(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be
>   loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Как её решить?

Comment: .NET core проект с Json-файлом проекта?

Comment: Да, progect.json имеется

Comment: @rdorn global.json: {
  "sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131" }
}

Comment: На одной машине компилится, на которой дорабатывался, на другой нет (залито с гита)

Comment: Что эта ошибка может означать? Гугл ничего толкового не ответил

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/ProjectJsonToCSProj.md последние два абзаца, видимо, ваши